# Module not appearing in list after pushing to Acquia Cloud

Tags: 7

I have added a new module in my local code repository. After adding, I committed and pushed it to my remote repository on Acquia Cloud, but it is still not showing up in the modules list.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried re-deploying from your branch on Acquia cloud? Also, have you checked you are deployed form the _correct_ branch?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's automated, you'll also need to pull to code from the remote repository onto your web server.